# Angular js example not working - error Argument 'UserCtrl as uCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wanted to try out the example discussed in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCR7i5F5L8c#t=587

I included 1.0.8 angular js and tried and it flung an error as

> Argument 'UserCtrl as uCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

so i thought aliasing was a problem and thought of removing aliasing and changed code to

index.html

> ```
> <html ng-app>
> <body ng-controller='UserCtrl'>
>   Hi <input ng-model='UserCtrl.user.first'>
>   <button ng-click='UserCtrl.bye()'>bye</button>
>   <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js'></script>
>   <script src='UserControllers.js'></script>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

UserControllers.js

```
function UserCtrl() {
  this.user = {
    first:'Larry', 
    last:'Page'
  };
  this.bye = function() { 
    alert('bye:' + this.user.first); 
  };
}
```

then the above mentioned error went off . But still what is mentioned in that video doesn't happen .I even checked in console and found no errors. The alert is not coming on clicking bye button.

I tried with angular js 1.0.7 and 1.0.8

Please help me to find the problem .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller "as" experimental feature was added in 1.1.5 so you're right that was causing issues.

Without "as" the controller is implicit so you don't need to prefix your variable names with it.

So you can either update to 1.1.5 or newer and stick with his use of "as" or here's a version of the code that works on earlier versions of Angular (fiddler here: http://jsfiddle.net/PDqbb/):

```
<body ng-app ng-controller='UserCtrl'>
  Hi <input ng-model='user.first'>
  <button ng-click='bye()'>bye</button>
</body>


function UserCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
    first:'Larry', 
    last:'Page'
  };
  $scope.bye = function() { 
    alert('bye:' + this.user.first); 
  };
}
```

Also, here's a nice overview on "as", which includes a bit on the use of "this" as it applies here:  http://www.thinkster.io/pick/GmI3KetKo6/angularjs-experimental-controller-as-syntax

Comment: Thank you . I changes version to 1.1.5 and it works now . Thanks .